# Refactoring code for summing the number of Dictionary entries matching a criteria

Tags: excel, vba

This code works and gives very accurate results considering I have in total several thousand entries. However, summing the matching entries takes a few seconds longer than what I would like.

I cannot disable application screen updating as there are progress bars to show the user that something is happening (many different processes run, so I don't want them thinking the application is stuck).

Here is my ugly but functional code. Or rather the part I would like to find a more efficient solution for:

```vb
Dim row as Integer

' a sheet where the buttons are located and a progress bar
Dim pSheet As Object
Set pSheet = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Process") 

' Sheet containigng a list of locations and the sum of different collections to be arranged per location (ANG,ARB,ANGAus, and ARBAus) need to be written here. Having approximately 800 locations
Dim oSheet As Object
Set oSheet = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output") 

'Collection of keys and items in dictionairies to prevent duplicates from being read into each classification.
Dim dictAng As New Scripting.Dictionary 
Dim dictArb As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim dictAusAng As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim dictAusArb As New Scripting.Dictionary

row = 0
For Each key In dictAng.Keys
    pSheet.Range("N12") = pSheet.Range("N12") + 1 'moves the progress bar up (using conditional formatting)
    row = WorksheetFunction.Match(dictAng.Item(key), oSheet.Range("E:E"), 0) 'find the dow matching the key
    oSheet.Cells(row, 7).Value = oSheet.Cells(row, 7).Value + 1 'add one to count the matching entry
Next

row = 0
For Each key In dictArb.Keys
    pSheet.Range("N12") = pSheet.Range("N12") + 1 'moves the progress bar up (using conditional formatting)
    row = WorksheetFunction.Match(dictArb.Item(key), oSheet.Range("E:E"), 0)
    oSheet.Cells(row, 8).Value = oSheet.Cells(row, 8).Value + 1
Next

row = 0
For Each key In dictAusAng.Keys
    pSheet.Range("N12") = pSheet.Range("N12") + 1 'moves the progress bar up (using conditional formatting)
    row = WorksheetFunction.Match(dictAusAng.Item(key), oSheet.Range("E:E"), 0) 
    oSheet.Cells(row, 9).Value = oSheet.Cells(row, 9).Value + 1 
Next

row = 0
For Each key In dictAusArb.Keys
    pSheet.Range("N12") = pSheet.Range("N12") + 1
    row = WorksheetFunction.Match(dictAusArb.Item(key), oSheet.Range("E:E"), 0)
    oSheet.Cells(row, 10).Value = oSheet.Cells(row, 10).Value + 1
Next
```

What the result looks like:

| Locations | ANG | ARB | ANGAus | ARBAus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Location1 | 5 | 200 | 2 | 0 |
| Location2 | 40 | 315 | 0 | 50 |
| Location3 | 4 | 35 | 0 | 3 |
| Location4 | 0 | 31 | 5 | 18 |
| Location5 | 10 | 55 | 0 | 30 |
| Location6 | 40 | 36 | 10 | 5 |

Comment: If your code is working but you'd like help with efficiency, [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be the appropriate place to post.

Comment: You could start by picking up the data from columns 7-10 into an array, then update the array before finally replacing it after incrementing the counts. Updating your progress bar for every count will cost you performance though.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from comment above:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim oSheet As Object, rngCounts As Range, arr, dict As Object, col As Long, rw As Long
    Dim key
    Dim dictAng As New scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dictArb As New scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dictAusAng As New scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dictAusArb As New scripting.Dictionary, dictRowMap As scripting.Dictionary
    
    Set oSheet = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")

    '...
    '...

    'range with counts
    Set rngCounts = oSheet.Range("G2:J" & oSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row)
    arr = rngCounts.Value
    
    Set dictRowMap = RowMap(rngCounts.EntireRow.Columns("E").Value) 'map values to position
    col = 1   'first array column to update
    For Each dict In Array(dictAng, dictArb, dictAusAng, dictAusArb)
        For Each key In dict.Keys
            If dictRowMap.Exists(key) Then
                arr(dictRowMap(key), col) = arr(dictRowMap(key), col) + 1
            End If
            Progress 1
        Next
        Progress dict.Count 'update with count of processed keys
        col = col + 1       'next array column to update
    Next dict
    
    rngCounts.Value = arr   'put updated array back on sheet

End Sub

'update Progress bar
Sub Progress(incr As Long)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Process").Range("N12")
        .Value = .Value + incr
    End With
End Sub

'Return a Scripting Dictionary linking "keys" to array position (row)
' Note - assumes single-column input to `arr`, and that keys are unique,
'     otherwise you just map to the *last* value for any given key
Function RowMap(arr) As scripting.Dictionary
    Dim n, dict As Object, k
    Set dict = New scripting.Dictionary
    For n = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        k = CStr(arr(n, 1))
        If Len(k) > 0 Then dict(k) = n
    Next n
    Set RowMap = dict
End Function
```

Comment: After some tinkering, it seems to work a bit faster. Thank you :)